# Using GUID for MySQL membership provider user

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using the ***MySql*** membership provider with a ***.NET MVC 4*** application and got it all set up as per [this tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-asp-roles.html).

The problem is that the provider sets up the `mysql_aspnet_users` table with the `UserID` ***PK*** as an `INT(11)`, whereas the ***MSSQL*** provider uses a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`.

I need to migrate existing users to this database and I would much prefer to keep a `Guid` as the primary key within the Users and Membership tables.

Is there any way to do this with the ***MySql membership provider***?

Or do I need to write my own ***MySql membership provider*** just to use `UUIDs` as the primary keys?

I've had a look for any documentation or "non-hacky" ways to do this but haven't had any luck so far.

Comment: +1 for the tutorial to set up MySQL membership

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can prevent creating a custom membership user class with a custom membership provider. Something like this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730%28v=VS.85%29.aspx they use GUID's as wel. You need to change the SQL abit so it works with MySQL

Comment: I looked into it further and had decided to do this, I will create my own MySQL membership provider as it seems like the only way to do it. Weird that they would not have that option but oh well.

Answer (score 0):

You can store a guid as a CHAR(16) binary if you want to make the most optimal use of storage space.
or varchar(36) if its ok .

---

http://mysqlbackupnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20MySQL%20With%20GUID%20or%20UUID

Comment: Thanks, I understand that you can store UUIDs in MySQL but I need to use them as the primary key for the user table using the MySQL membership provider.

Answer (score 0):

At work we ended up creating our own MySql membership provider for .NET and it's called Dolphin https://github.com/film-skills/dolphin-net! It also includes a role provider, and allows you to specify in the config whether you use a GUID or an Integer. It's still in very early days and hasn't been tested thouroughly in production though it's a start! Also on NuGet http://www.nuget.org/packages/Dolphin/0.0.2